# How to create a table using the Barracuda file format

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

Since I need several mediumtext fields I need the barracuda file format. There are many articales and videos on how to convert an existing antelope table to barracuda but none on how to create a new table using barracuda. Is there an easy to do this with MariaDB? I'd like to use a docker container if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.23-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_format';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| innodb_file_format | Antelope |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE `barracuda_table` (`col` MEDIUMTEXT) ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                            |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1478 | InnoDB: ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC requires innodb_file_format > Antelope. |
| Warning | 1478 | InnoDB: assuming ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT.                               |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT ROW_FORMAT
    -> FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
    -> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND
    ->       `TABLE_NAME` = 'barracuda_table';
+------------+
| ROW_FORMAT |
+------------+
| Compact    |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE `barracuda_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SET @@GLOBAL.innodb_file_format = 'Barracuda';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_format';
+--------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name      | Value     |
+--------------------+-----------+
| innodb_file_format | Barracuda |
+--------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE `barracuda_table` (`col` MEDIUMTEXT) ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT ROW_FORMAT
    -> FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
    -> WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE() AND
    ->       `TABLE_NAME` = 'barracuda_table';
+------------+
| ROW_FORMAT |
+------------+
| Dynamic    |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT `NAME`, `FILE_FORMAT`, `ROW_FORMAT`
    -> FROM `information_schema`.`INNODB_SYS_TABLES`
    -> WHERE `NAME` = '_/barracuda_table';
+-------------------+-------------+------------+
| NAME              | FILE_FORMAT | ROW_FORMAT |
+-------------------+-------------+------------+
| _/barracuda_table | Barracuda   | Dynamic    |
+-------------------+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [XtraDB/InnoDB Storage Formats](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/).

Answer (score 3):

It's messy in 5.6 (MariaDB 10.0 and 10.1):

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;     -- optional (if you also need wide indexes)
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

It's possibly defaulted correctly in 5.7 (MariaDB 10.2).

Comment: Switching to Barracuda file_format can be done only at global - OR - is there a way to specify it for a Database alone?

Comment: @RKajaMohideen - Check the docs (or try it), but I don't think you need to worry about Barracuda, except for getting your one table set up.  You may as well add it to my.cnf so that all future tables are Barracuda.  The only drawback (very unlikely) is if you ever need to downgrade to a version that does not support B.

Comment: ```USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;```
Followed by:
```SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;") AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "<database_name>";```